# Overview/map of pollution level of worldwide fishing zones

Tags: ocean, pollution

Is there any up-to date and reliable map or overview or database of the oceans pollution with respect to fish pollution (PCB, mercury, dioxines, tin compounds etc.)?

Comment: Your are looking for global data? I would assume that there is no such map available. For Europe this might help: The ICES (Int. Council for Explor. of the Seas) might be a good start. They refer to a database named [DOME](http://www.ices.dk/marine-data/data-portals/Pages/DOME.aspx), which is also used by OSPAR and HELCOM. Generally, you could look for other sources and reports provided by ICES.

Comment: Not fish related and not primarily focussed on the ocean (but some of their work is focussed on the ocean) is the work of the Global Mercury Observation System ([GMOS](http://www.gmos.eu/)). A look at the projects homepage might help. Some colleagues of mine worked on heavy metal pollution of North Sea waters in the past. However, heavy metals do not seem to be in the focus of your question.

Comment: Finally, within European waters, the Marine Strategy Framework Directive ([MSFD](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32008L0056&from=DE)) came into force some years ago. The target of the MSFD is to describe the "good environmental status" on European waters by 10 [descriptors](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/marine/good-environmental-status/index_en.htm). The EU member states have to collect data for these descriptors and report it to the EU. Descriptor 9 (Contaminants in Seafood) might be of your interest.

Comment: One more :-) . Could you specify the follwoing points: global data? Does it need to be a visual representation of that data? How reliable does the data need to be (which origin)? A database as the linked DOME database would be OK? You are looking for concentrations of pollutants within fish but not in the water: A particular fish type? You are looking for measurement and not for modeling data? Are there certain regions of the world that are of special interest for you?

Comment: @daniel.neumann Yes I want a worldwide overview. A visual representation would be nice but is not necessary and if I have the data as a table I will probably generate one by myself. The database should be reliable. A global overview of the pollutants in the water would be sufficient (but having in mind that I want to conclude something about the fish). An *ideal* answer would be a global map where you can choose the pollutant and the fish type and get a visual representation of the global distribution.